# How to Disable Lidar on Turtlebot3

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to compare the performance of Odom(wheels) and Lidar. I managed to examine the accuracy of the lidar while the Turtelbot3 is not moving. Now I'm trying to investigate how accurate the odom is without interference from lidar. Is there a way to turn off the lidar while navigating?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399194/how-to-disable-lidar-on-turtlebot3/) by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it depends on the navigation stack being used.
If this is your implementation, you can just ignore the LiDAR information.

Can you add more details in the question?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-04-19**:
(If not in simulation)  Just unplug the lidar USB, It will still bring-up properly and save some battery as well ;)

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-04-19**:
@ljaniec first of all thank you so much! And to be more specific as I mentioned I am testing the accuracy of the Turtlebot3 for further use in a reinforcement learning project. First I used a node that makes the robot move forward a certain distance, then I noticed that the robot drives with a certain deviation and not exactly forward, or it sometimes stops and spins at the end of the target, so I figured it was cause od the two sensors being combined, and it would be better to test each one individually. So far, as I said, I've been testing the lidar while the robot isn't moving, and now I'm trying to analyze the wheels while moving the Turtlebot3 in a direction and then recording it in a bag file... is there a proper way, to all of that? I'd be so grateful!

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-04-19**:
@aarsh_t im unfortunately using Simulation right now!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-19**:
Just to be sure - do you know about recovery behaviors in Navigation stack? These rotations could be a part of it. You can read about it [there](https://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf).

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-04-19**:
I have seen these type of issues on the actual robots but in simulation its strange! Can I ask if you are using navigation stack or your own path planning algorithm?

In real life when we face issue like this, we try to set low P gain. Because even at near the goal robot is going at high speed due to high P gain and it cause the robot to never reach the actual goal and just encircles around it.

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-04-23**:
@ljaniec Thanks again! and yes I've seen it before but I'm ashamed of myself I have to say because I can't use it! I still can't figure out how to configure or use ros parameters!

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-04-23**:
@aarsh_t Thanks a lot!  im gonna try this...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, if you comment out launch file for it i.e. turtlebot3_lidar.launch in turtlebot3_bringup, then it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Asad775889](https://answers.ros.org/users/99432/asad775889/) with karma: 21 on 2022-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-04-19**:
Thank u so much! im gonna try that.